# How to compile ffmpeg in yocto to get a working binary

Tags: ffmpeg, yocto

In our yocto project,the SDK has default "poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_3.3.3.bb" bb file. and this is our bbappend file
meta-qti-bsp/recipes-multimedia/ffmpeg/**ffmpeg_%.bbappend**

```
    EXTRA_OEMAKE = ""

FILES_${PN} += "/lib/lib*.so.*" FILES_${PN} += "/lib/pkgconfig/*" FILES_${PN}-dev += "/usr/share/*" FILES_${PN}-dev += "/lib/lib*.so"

PACKAGECONFIG = "avdevice avfilter avcodec avformat swresample swscale postproc bzlib gpl theora"

# Support multilib compilation for libav PROVIDES += "${MLPREFIX}libav"

EXTRA_CFLAGS_append += " -fPIC" EXTRA_CFLAGS_append += " ${@ bb.utils.contains('TUNE_FEATURES', 'callconvention-hard', '-mfloat-abi=hard', '', d)}" EXTRA_CFLAGS_append += " ${@ bb.utils.contains('TUNE_FEATURES', 'neon', '-mfpu=neon', '', d)}" EXTRA_CFLAGS_append += " ${@ bb.utils.contains('TUNE_FEATURES', 'armv7a', '-march=armv7-a', '', d)}" EXTRA_CFLAGS_append += " ${@ bb.utils.contains('TUNE_FEATURES', 'cortexa8', '-mtune=cortex-a8', '', d)}"

EXTRA_OECONF_append += " \
    --target-os=linux --sysroot=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET} --arch=${TARGET_ARCH} --disable-mmx \
    --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages \
    --disable-txtpages --enable-small --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay \
    --extra-cflags="${EXTRA_CFLAGS}" --disable-network --disable-zlib \
    --enable-fft --libdir=${base_libdir} --shlibdir=${base_libdir} \
    --enable-muxer=mov --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-encoders --enable-zlib --enable-encoder=png \
    --prefix=${base_libdir} --incdir=${includedir} \ "

do_install() {
    oe_runmake 'DESTDIR=${D}' install
    # Info dir listing isn't interesting at this point so remove it if it exists.
    if [ -e "${D}${infodir}/dir" ]; then
    rm -f ${D}${infodir}/dir
    fi }  NORMAL
```

with this I could able to get ffmpeg bin. I pushed it on to the device (vr360 chipset: qcs605).
But when I try to invoke any ffmpeg commands say

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i "input.mp4"  -t 00:01:00 "out.mp4"
```

I'm getting this error

> [NULL @ 0xaf61a380] Unable to find a suitable output format for
> 'out.mp4' out.mp4: Invalid argument

for all ffmpeg operation related to video/image processing I'm getting the same error.

Is there anything else,do I need to enable ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the ffmpeg_%.bbappend file with

> --enable-ffmpeg

and also edit the local.conf file with

> IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " ffmpeg ffmpeg-staticdev"

and compile the whole image using bitbake.